# Can't update form inside of onBlur in redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have a field `AskQuestions` where a user enters something and a dropdown appears on each user keystroke with updated results in an array, `companyOptions`. However, when a user clicks out of a field I am trying to clear current field's value via `this.props.dispatch(change..))` but this seems impossible.

```
<Field
  name="company"
  type="text"
  onBlur={this.onClearSearch}
  keyUp={this.renderCompanyList}
  component={renderField}
  label="Choose Company..."/>
```

here is my renderField

```
 function renderField(field) {
    const { meta: {touched, error} } = field;
    return(
    <div>
      <input type={field.type}
             placeholder={field.label}
             onKeyUp={field.keyUp ? () => {field.keyUp(field.input.value)} : ""}
             onBlur={field.onBlur ? () =>{field.onBlur()} : ""}
             {...field.input}
             // I also tried putting in after ...input
             // onBlur={field.onBlur ? () =>{field.onBlur()} : ""}
           />
           <div className="text-danger">
             {touched ? error : ''}
           </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have the following callback associated, but this.props.dispatch does not reset the field.

```
onClearSearch(){
   this.props.dispatch(change('AskQuestion','company',''));
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any console errors in your browser when onBlur appears? is your function being called? (debug or console log it)

Comment: i have logged and i am getting inside of the else {...} clause. this.props.dispatch is being fired, but the change is not happening. i am not getting any errors.

Answer (score 4):

it's because there are an default event `onBlur` which modifies the value of the input after having been modified by your function onClearSearch,

Add an `e.preventDefault()` at the end of `onClearSearch` will have to  solved your problem, something like this:

```
onClearSearch(e){
   const {companyOptions} = this.state;
   if (companyOptions.length){
     var company = companyOptions[0];
     this.props.dispatch(change('AskQuestion','company',company.label));
   }
   else {
     this.props.dispatch(change('AskQuestion','company',''));
   }
   // hides the dropdown view
   this.setState({showCompanySearch:false})
   // here
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

[More info here](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2768)

I hope this can help you

Comment: Thanks, man! You have just terminated my 2-hour struggle with `onBlur`!